# In Android how to make ObjectAnimator translate on top of the other imageviews and not below?

Tags: android, objectanimator

I have some imageviews which I am translating using

```
ObjectAnimator moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stone, "y", catPos[1] );
```

When it translates to the specified position,and there is already another image view there, it places itself under the imageview. I want the newly moved imageview to be seen on top. How can i do that?

Comment: What kind of layout are you using? If it's a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout, all you'd have to do is add the item after the View it's passing underneath (e.g. add it further below in the XML), as that will naturally give it a z-index above the the View. You can't use a LinearLayout for that, though. Calling bringToFont() on the View should also work, assuming you're using a compatible layout.

Comment: I am using RelativeLayout,but am translating the imageviews on runtime, depending on userclick, so sometimes one imageview needs to be on top and sometimes the other. will try bringToFront and check. Thankyou

Comment: No problem, in that case, bringToFront() is definitely what you'd want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Adding code bringToFont() worked.